# API for admin login authentication in Magento

Tags: php, api, magento, authentication

Is there is  any Api  for admin login authentication in Magento?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think magento have the extensions for admin authentications  [This may will help you](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=admin+login+authentication&pl=0)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['admin_name']) && isset($_REQUEST['admin_password']))
             $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
             $user->login($_REQUEST['admin_name'],$_REQUEST['admin_password']);
             $result=$user->getId();
             if($result)
             {
                 $result1=$user->getUsername();
                 $result2=$user->getFirstname();
                 $result3=$user->getLastname();
                 $result4= $user->getEmail();
                 echo $result4;
             }
```

Comment: you can check admin authentication using soap with above code

Comment: nice answer, maybe that's what was meant in the question. voted.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what do you want to achieve. So I have provided guidance for three possible goals.

**1) If you want to authenticate admin via some 3rd party system**, so he doesn't need to enter his credentials in the standard "Login/Password" form, **then you need to engage Magento codebase flexibility** and install some custom solution or write it on your own. There is no feature of 3rd party authentication out of the box, because it is too specialized and there are numerous auth providers / APIs.

Like any system Magento cannot be a Swiss knife for everything, providing all the solutions with the initial system package. Instead the platform comes with many useful e-commerce features plus ability to be fully customized. Thus, if any store owner wants a new feature for his store, then he can easily develop his own custom solution. Or try to find one at Magento Connect (i.e. Magento's App Store), a [link to which](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=admin%20login%20authentication&pl=0) has already been provided by @naveen.

**2) If you want to use API to perform some backend actions (product creation, customer management, etc.) on behalf of admin user, then you can use Magento's REST or SOAP APIs.** Note that these systems does not use admin accounts, rather they have their own users, which are configured at the backend. You can find more information on Magento API in the [official documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html).

**3) If you want to use internal API to verify admin login and password in PHP, then you should use `Mage_Admin_Model_User` or `Mage_Admin_Model_Session` for that.**

There are two methods in `Mage_Admin_Model_User` for authentication:

- `authenticate($username, $password)` - loads user model, returns whether authentication is successful

```
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
if ($adminUser->authenticate($username, $password)) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
     echo 'Failure';
}
```

- `login($username, $password)` - loads user model, logs unsuccessful authenticate tries

```
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$adminUser->login($username, $password)
if ($adminUser->getId()) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failure';
}
```

And there is one method in `Mage_Admin_Model_Session` - `login($username, $password)`. The model itself is designed to manage admin session - start it upon successful login, set cookies to browser, let admin browse backend after logging in. The `login()` method starts new session and returns user model, if login was successful.

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminUser = $adminSession->login($username, $password)
if ($adminUser) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Failure';
}
```